# Explain the N-rules in hook_update_N

Tags: 7, updating

On [hook_update_N()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_update_N/7) the documentation says:

> mymodule_update_7000(): This is the ***required*** update for mymodule to
>   run with Drupal core API 7.x **when upgrading from Drupal core API 6.x**.

> mymodule_update_7200(): This is the first update to get the database
>   ready to run mymodule 7.x-2.*. **Users can directly update from 6.x-2.***
>   to 7.x-2.* and they get all 70xx and 72xx updates, ***but not 71xx***
>   updates, because those reside in the 7.x-1.x branch only.

Is it really mandatory to define an 7000 update hook? I saw some contributed module updates that starts with 7300, when the module version for Drupal 7 is 7.x-3.x.

I am a bit confused, because I read before the UPGRADE.txt file for Drupal 7 core that says:

> MAJOR VERSION UPGRADE
>   To upgrade from a previous major version of Drupal to Drupal 7.x, after following the instructions in the
>   INTRODUCTION section at the top of this file:
>
> 3. In addition to updating to the latest available version of Drupal 6.x core,    you must also **upgrade all of your contributed modules for Drupal to their    latest Drupal 6.x versions**.

For me, it means that users can't directly update from 6.x-2.x to 7.x-2.x unless  6.x-2.x module was the latest in the Drupal 6.x versions. Is this correct?

What about eventual database updates defined by 7.x-1.x branch? Do they have to be reported in the 70xx updates?

Can a module version 7.2.x keep any other updates (e.g. 60xx, 71xx) or it should be clean and defined **only** updates about 70xx and 72xx?

Comment: It seems that as you are asking multiple questions, it will be difficult to answer. Is there a specific real-world question you are asking?

Comment: I can spread it into multiple issues questions related. But I'm not sure that it is the best way because all sub questions are in fact related to a same global issue (N version in hook_update_N)

Comment: Perhaps retitle something like "Explain the N-rules in hook_update_N".

Comment: As far as I recall, what described there was planned, but the actual code just executes any update that has not been yet executed, without making any difference between 71xx and 72xx. I cannot find anything in the code that checks if the installed module was 6.2.x, or 6.1.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basing on the documentation, 70xx updates are only necessary if there are updates from Drupal 6.x to Drupal 7.x that are necessary for any branch the Drupal 7 module has (e.g. 7.x-1.x, 7.x-2.x, 7.x-3.x). If that is not the case, then you don't need to use 70xx as update numbers.

As said in the documentation, updates numbered 72xx allows updating from the 6.x-2-x version of the module to the 7.x-2.x version, but not from the 6.x-3.x version. This is generally not a problem, since project maintainers normally create a version 7.x-3.x together a version 6.x-3.x.

As the documentation reports, updates numbered 71xx are for updated from version 6.x-1.x to 7.x-1.x; updates numbered 70xx are for updates from Drupal 6 to any branch of the module for Drupal 7.x. You don't copy the 70xx updates in 71xx updates, since those are already executed for the 7.x-1.x branch.

As for the updates to keep, the documentation says:

> A good rule of thumb is to remove updates older than two major releases of Drupal.

So, updates for a 7.x-1.x version should still be kept for a 7.x-2.x version.

Keep in mind that, as far as I recall, what described in the documentation about which updates are run when updating from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7 doesn't describe what the code actually does. For what I recall, Drupal code simply run any updates higher than the last executed update. For example, if a module last time ran its 6123 update, Drupal will run any update higher than that number, such as 7000, 7100, and 7200, if they are defined.

Comment: a)I am confused when you say about this topic that what described in the documentation doesn't describe what the code actually does. This is a little bit worrying! 
Otherwise, ok I understand now that in theory, for e.g 73xx was planned to be executed only for the 7.x-3.x branch (either for an updating from the 6.x-3.x branch or from previous 7.x branches, regardless). And in case of updating from the 6.x-3.x branch, we should in theory use 7000 update, in addition.

Comment: b) When you say: "You don't copy the 70xx updates in 71xx updates, since those are already executed for the 7.x-1.x branch."
You meant "..in 72xx updates" ?

Comment: c) Documentation says : "A good rule of thumb is to remove updates older than two major releases of Drupal."
Is it an error when they say two major releases of Drupal ? They meant two module's major release version ?